# how to prevent imageView from shrinking beyond the size of its containing items in constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am designing a `constraint layout` for an android application and I want the layout to look something like this:

[image: layout]

The problem is that as soon as I `constraint` the height of the image views, they shrink until there is nothing left. I want the image views to have at least as much height as the `text views` they surround, plus a little padding. How can I do that without specifying an absolute height for the image views?

**Here is my XML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLightBlue">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView13"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_round_bg_off" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView14"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView12"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_round_bg_off" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView13"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_round_bg_off" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView14"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView14"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView14"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView14" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView12"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView12"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView12"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView12" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView13"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView13"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView13"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView13" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="Image description."
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView13"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imageView14" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView14"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="Image description."
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView12"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="Image description."
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imageView12"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView14"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView14"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView14"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView14" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView12"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView12"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView12"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView12" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView13"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView13"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView13"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView13" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Use the above code and save the "Image description." in the strings.xml file and as you can notice that the imageView12 is not having app:srcCompat attribute in which you are specifying your drawable but still all the three image views are having the same distribution in terms of space occupied by them. Also, I have given padding of "15dp" to all the three text views which you may manage as per your requirement. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I do not want to use absolute height and width as they may cause problems in devices with different screen size. I would like to use an approach that uses wrap_content attribute but understands that the textbox is in it.

Comment: I think, what you want to achieve as the overall result (as per your given attachment) can simply be achieved by applying "background" to the three text views and there is no requirement of using the image views if that's the case. If you wish, I can edit my answer and post the code that would reflect the same layout as you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is one magical attribute in ConstraintLayout.

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_min="wrap"
```

And I think you have constraint reversed. ImageView should constraintTo the TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2222">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView13"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView16"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView16"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_min="wrap"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView16"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_message_check" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This will not allow ImageView's height to go below "wrap_content" value. But if you chose this you will have to make sure height of the TextView will be at least that of "wrap" of the ImageView.

But this should be the only caveat. ImageView will automatically resize based on height of the TextView(and wrap of the width)